# Modify hexbinplot figure width or make plot(hexbin(x)) work with par? (in R)

Tags: r

I have a 2 column matrix `x` and I want to do a simple hexplot.
If i do `plot(hexbin(x))` I get a nice and rather square plot which is fine, but will not work if I want to let's say draw 3 such plots in 1 row as `par` does not work here.

Another option would be to use `hexbinplot(x[,2] ~ x[,1])` and `grid.arrange`. The problem is that when I use `hexbinplot(x[,2] ~ x[,1])` I get the same plot but the plot is like super tall and slim (like 10 height and 2 width) and whatever I do, it keeps this weird ratio.

So my question is: is there a way to fix/modify/fine-tune `hexbinplot`'s final plot length/width ratio or is there a way to make `plot(hexbin(x))` work with `par` or `grid`?

I have added a sample of such a matrix here:

```
> x
      projsizes   
 [1,]      2865  2
 [2,]      2737  2
 [3,]       802  2
 [4,]      2738  5
 [5,]      3384  4
 [6,]      3432  2
 [7,]      2333  2
 [8,]      1713  1
 [9,]      2893  6
[10,]      1010  1
[11,]      1735  3
[12,]      1961  1
[13,]      2534  5
[14,]      2117  4
[15,]      3086  8
[16,]      4784  7
[17,]      2185  1
[18,]       966  2
[19,]      4170  3
[20,]      4958  5
[21,]       383  1
[22,]      2926  2
[23,]      2733  1
[24,]      1478  5
[25,]      2702 17
[26,]      4628  6
[27,]      1207  2
[28,]      4118  2
[29,]      1737  1
[30,]      3157  1
[31,]      2051  1
[32,]       927  1
[33,]      2047  1
[34,]      4452  4
[35,]      1784  2
[36,]      4110  2
[37,]      4406 14
[38,]       861  3
[39,]       875  4
[40,]      3310  5
[41,]      3133  5
[42,]      4290  5
[43,]      4615  8
[44,]      1661  1
[45,]      4479  5
[46,]      3752  2
[47,]      3739  9
[48,]      1139  1
[49,]      4177  5
[50,]      1707  2
[51,]      1447  3
[52,]      1028  1
[53,]      3504  4
[54,]      4093 15
[55,]      3689  6
[56,]      2821  4
[57,]      3326  1
[58,]      3111  7
[59,]       906 10
[60,]      4602  2
```

Answer (score 1):

apparently the `aspect` parameter does the trick for `hexbinplot`:

```
hexbinplot(x[,2] ~ x[,1], aspect=1)
```